# Adding mapbox markers dynamically on click

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I was just trying to create mapbox markers when I click on checkboxes. At the moment, I can create markers statically when the map loads

Current code with markers on load

```
<Map>

<Marker longitude={lng} latitude={lat} anchor="bottom" >
<img className='w-6' src= {pin} />
</Marker> 

<Marker longitude={lng2} latitude={lat2} anchor="bottom" >
<img className='w-6' src= {pin} />
</Marker> 

</Map>
```

what im trying to do to click on this checkbox to create a new marker inside the Map.

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick={generateNewMarker} />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you may add a state variable to keep track of the marker coordinates, then add an 'onClick' event handler to the 'Map' component, which will update the 'markercoordinates' state variable with the new marker coordinates. Finally, map over the 'markercoordinates' state variable to render the 'Marker' components for each set of coordinates.

you may try something like this:

```
const [markerCoordinates, setMarkerCoordinates] = useState([]);

return (
  <Map onClick={(mapEvent) => {
    const { lngLat } = mapEvent;
    setMarkerCoordinates([...markerCoordinates, [lngLat.lng, lngLat.lat]]);
  }}>
    {markerCoordinates.map((coordinates, index) => (
      <Marker key={index} longitude={coordinates[0]} latitude={coordinates[1]} anchor="bottom">
        <img className='w-6' src={pin} />
      </Marker>
    ))}
  </Map>
);
```

Comment: But my checkbox is outside the made component. Thanks !